# I can't repeat a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, timer, repeat

I'm trying to write a simple tabata timer. Until now it work but the problem comes in when I try to repeat the count more times depending on the value stored in a variable.
So, imagine we start from 10 to 0 and we want to repeat this count twice. would say: when I press the button, before the count starts, the program will check if the variable with the number of times is NaN or if it has a number in it. If is NaN because I didn't want to repeat, it just starts to count down from 10 to 0 and it stops. Ok, this part works. But what if I say I want to repeat the count down twice? I put in the variable called "var times" the number of times I want to repeat, let's say 2, then I would use a for loop like:

```
  for(var i=0; i<times; i++){}
```

But when I start the countdown, instead of repeating twice it skips many numbers as the times variable value. Why is that?

Thanks in advance

Here is my code.

```js
var times = 2;
var counter = 0;
var operation;

document.getElementById("timer").textContent = 10;

function calculate(){

    counter = document.getElementById("timer").textContent
    operation = setInterval(function(){
        if(counter >= 1 && counter <= 10){
            counter -- ;
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent = counter;

        }
        else if(counter == 0){
            clearInterval(operation);
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent = 10;
            
            
        }

    },1000);

}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

    for(var i=0; i<times; i++){

        calculate();
    }
   
})
```

```css
.btn{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.timer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top:30%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="btn">

            <button id="btn">

                <h1>Click me</h1>

            </button>

        </div>

        <div class="timer">

            <p id="timer"></p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is a *"simple tabata timer"*?

Comment: Because you are calling ````setInterval```` multiple times, which results in multiple decrements/increments.

Comment: BTW you should probably not use `NaN` but something like `null`, because `NaN` has some properties that you probably don't want for example it is _not equal to itself_ (`NaN != NaN`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem there is that when you do the for loop it is calling twice the setinterval, so for this case What You have to do is to use Recursion, here's a working code for this case->

```js
var times = 2;
var counter = 0;
var operation;

document.getElementById("timer").textContent = 10;

function calculate(){
    counter = document.getElementById("timer").textContent
    operation = setInterval(function(){
        if(counter >= 1 && counter <= 10){
            counter -- ;
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent =   counter;
        }
        else if(counter == 0){
          times--
          console.log(times)
          if(times > 0){
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent = 10;
            clearInterval(operation);
            calculate()
          }else if(times == 0){
            clearInterval(operation);
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent = 10;
          }                
        }
       

    },1000);

}
```

```css
.btn{
  z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    
}

.timer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top:30%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="btn">

            <button onClick="calculate()" id="btn">

                <h1>Click me</h1>

            </button>

        </div>

        <div class="timer">

            <p id="timer"></p>

        </div>

    </div>

    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh my god! It was quite simple but I really couldn't find the solution. I've tried different ways in the last 7 days but never reached this solution. So you have done the job without using any loop! No for and no while! I even tried to skip using loops but the only thing I tried was to call the calculate function twice in sequence, which was not working. So you say that I had to clear the interval in any way, but if the counter was greater than 0 just call again the calculate function. I think i'm figuring out the sense of what you have done! Thank you sooooo MUCH!

Comment: You're welcome, It was quite tricky, but like I said you have to use recursion,to me it is the best way to do It, dont forget to upvote this.And yes, you have to clear the interval each time you call it again, if not it chains.

Comment: Last thing... I upvoted your answer but the page shows this message: " Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." If I can do anything else, please tell me. Thanks again, Ciao!

Answer (score 0):

First of all not sure if your logic works or not. I just looking into the code without testing, it seems `calculate()` > `operation = setInterval(function(){...` is calling a call back function, which will execute asynchronized.

if you call `calculate()` twice, it will just trigger the asynchronized method twice at the same time, not in sequence.

It means your logic inside `calculate()` executed twice at the same time, not in sequence.

you can pass in the `times` variable into the function like `calculate(times)`, and perform the loop in it, see below example

```js
function calculate(times){

    counter = document.getElementById("timer").textContent
    operation = setInterval(function(){
      /////////////////////////////
      // do the times loop here
      /////////////////////////////
      for(let i=0; i < times; i++){
        if(counter >= 1 && counter <= 10){
            counter -- ;
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent = counter;
        } else if(counter == 0) {
            clearInterval(operation);
            document.getElementById("timer").textContent = 10;
        }
      }
    },1000);

}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

        calculate(times);

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply... I tried your way but the timer keeps skipping two number while counting down